# Selenium NoSuchDriverError IE Protected mode VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer

I'm getting an error trying to launch IE w/ Selenium Web Driver.

> Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (NoSuchDriver).

[image]

I know one fix is to resolve the actual problem, but I'm more concerned with making my code able to work around the issue.

I've seen this fix in C#, but I don't know how I can use this in VBA. Any pointers? --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/13384197/5079799

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions;
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
var driver = new InternetEplorerDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the description, it looks like you are using the **IE VBA Automation** approach but to fix the issue you are referring to the **Selenium Web Driver** solution.

You will not be able to **set capability** in the **IE VBA Automation**.

To fix this issue, you need to go to the `Internet options-> Security` tab.

Whether **checked** or **unchecked** the `Enable Protected Mode` option for all the zones. **Keep the same value for all zones.**

[image]

It will fix the error and you can continue to run the code.

Let me know if I misunderstand something from your description, I will try to correct myself.

Comment: Apologises, but I specifically said I know this resolution. Fix the error

Comment: If, it turns out the answer is, you can't, I'll adjust my vote and accept. (I think it might be impossible). But, I have faith in SO

Comment: If only I could control the settings of every user everywhere

Comment: I'm looking for reasons to switch from basic COM interaction and  I'm not impressed ( not ur fault)

Comment: I suspect you are correct. The main reason I want my code to work regardless is due to my inability to control all end users terminal. Can you provide the methods that are possible with admin priv?

Comment: As I already informed you will not be able to control it using the IE VBA Automation code even with the admin privileges. So you have manually configured it on each instance. You can mention it as a requirement for your automation code to make it work on your client-side.